# Ensure only specific list of users exist with Ansible

Tags: ansible

We use Ansible to create users with this task:

```
- name: Create adm users
  user:
    name: "{{ item.name }}"
    group: "{{ common_adm_group }}"
    createhome: yes
    password: "!!"
    update_password: always
    state: present
  with_items: "{{ common_adm_users }}"
```

And common_adm_users is like this:

```
  - name: user1
    comment: "First Last"
    ssh_key: "ssh-rsa AAAAB3Nza..."
```

This works fine for creating users, but when someone leaves the team, just removing their user from common_adm_users doesn't cause it to be removed from the servers when we re-apply the role that includes this task.

What is the best practice to maintain an exact list of users?

Comment: You're correct, the ansible user module is very basic. For what you want you'll either be rolling your own role, using something from [ansible galaxy](https://galaxy.ansible.com), or using external auth (LDAP, AD, etc.).

Comment: Why don't you just `state: absent` the sacked users?

Answer (score 11):

This is a similar answer to @Konstantin Suvorov's but a bit more refined, with some nuances clearly spelled out, and actually tested and in-use.

Using the following, you only need maintain a single list of usernames you wish to have access. Any additions or removals from that list will be reflected in host access.

*Optional helpful tip: We actually choose to use our GitHub usernames for this list, as then we can easily add SSH keys as well. See the end for an example.*

First, in our `group_vars` we define our list of developers we wish to have access (note that this can be defined in multiple ways, not just `group_vars`):

```
developers:
  - user1
  - user2
  - etc...
```

Second, we create a group for which we will assign our developers to:

```
- name: Create "developers" group
  group:
    name: developers
    state: present
```

Third, we add our developers to this group. **NOTE that we add them via the `groups` and not `group` property. This adds it as a secondary group and ensures they appear in `/etc/group`. This is critical because if you add them as a primary group, they will not appear as a member of that group in `/etc/group`:**

```
- name: Add user accounts
  user:
    name: "{{ item }}"
    shell: /bin/bash
    groups: [developers]
    state: present
  with_items: "{{ developers }}"
```

Fourth, we then get all users that currently belong to the developers group on the host (**Note that this is dependent on the primary/secondary assumption mentioned in the prior step**) :

```
- name: Determine existing users
  shell: 'grep developers /etc/group | cut -d: -f4 | tr "," "\n"'
  changed_when: false 
  register: existing_users
```

Fifth, determine which of those users should be removed (e.g. those that are not defined in our `developers` group_vars list):

```
- name: Determine removed users
  set_fact:
    removed_users: "{{ existing_users.stdout_lines | difference(developers) }}"
```

Sixth and last, remove them:

```
- name: Delete removed user accounts
  user:
    name: "{{ item }}"
    state: absent
  with_items: "{{ removed_users }}"
```

*Optional helpful step - If adding users by GitHub username, you can easily grant them SSH access from the public key they have available on GitHub:*

```
- name: Add public ssh keys of users
  authorized_key:
    user: "{{ item }}"
    exclusive: yes
    key: https://github.com/{{ item }}.keys
    state: present
  with_items: "{{ developers }}"
```

Comment: Very well explained, this should be the accepted answer.

Comment: Very nice, that github provides a keys endpoint! Thanks for the hint!

Answer (score 3):

You need to do some extra tasks here.

After adding all required users, grab existing users, e.g.:

```
- shell: 'grep {{ common_adm_group }} /etc/group | cut -d: -f4 | tr "," "\n"'
  changed_when: false # Make task green
  register: existing_users
```

and remove stale ones:

```
- user:
    name: "{{ item }}"
    state: absent
  with_items: "{{ existing_users.stdout_lines | difference(common_adm_users | map(attribute='name') | list) }}"
```

*Note: code is not tested, may contain typos etc.*

Answer (score 0):

You could actually just add a field to your existing task:

```
- name: Create adm users
  user:
    name: "{{ item.name }}"
    group: "{{ common_adm_group }}"
    createhome: yes
    password: "!!"
    update_password: always
    state: "{{ item.state | default('present') }}"
  with_items: "{{ common_adm_users }}"
```

And then make the data for leaving team members look like:

```
- name: user1
    comment: "First Last"
    ssh_key: "ssh-rsa AAAAB3Nza..."
    state: "absent"
```